# Suppress Babylon's term suggestions in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, spell-check, babylon

In MS Word, Babylon makes term suggestions which can be displayed by the right-click menu. I don't want to use this feature of Babylon, but I can't find the place to disable it. Does anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Research Options, click on the Update/Remove and look for the dictionary you want to disable.

[image]

UPDATE: I don't have Babylon in my Word, probably you installed it. Most probably you will find it in the add-ins. Go to Word Options | Add-ins and look for the Babylon Dictionary add-in and remove it.

You may also find some other work around here:http://www.proz.com/forum/software_applications/137932-babylon_8_and_its_ms_word_enhanced_by_babylon_feature.html

Comment: I followed your suggestion but there is nothing related to darn Babylon neither in Research Options services list nor in Update/Remove box. The listed options are all from Microsoft Office's default services. I checked them one by one.

Comment: UPDATE: I don'have Babylon in my Word, probably you installed it. Most probably you will find it in the add-ins. Go to Word Options | Add-ins and look for the Babylon Dictionary add-in and remove it.

You may also find some other work around here:http://www.proz.com/forum/software_applications/137932-babylon_8_and_its_ms_word_enhanced_by_babylon_feature.html

Comment: Aha, it's there inside COM add-ins. Thanks a lot. Case solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can erase the file:

```
E:\Program Files\Babylon\Babylon-Pro\Utils\BabylonIEPI.dll
```

(where E: is my default drive, but yours may be C:).

You can also backup the file or rename it.

Then close Word 2007 and reopen it.